# How to use arm-int64?

Tags: arm, ida

now int32 **MOV R0, #0x1** code good working 
but int64 not working.

**MOV R0,** instead what should i use?

Do you guys help?

Comment: This depends on the architecture you are using. Some new ARM, ARMv8 instruction set, do have 64-bit move. It's the same *MOV* but with wide registers and literals.

Comment: What should I write?

arm little endian so ARM

I want to do only enter a number but int64 accept

Comment: what core are you using, what architecture and what did you find when you read the architectural reference manual from arms website for that core/architecture?

Comment: Or to try it a different way what did you find when you took a simple C program that performed a similar assignment, compiled then disassembled it?

Comment: now for int64 MOV R0, #0x1 but "0" is happening
It is not "1"

Comment: like this image

https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/3peYF4jD.png

Comment: Please update your question to explain exactly what "not working" means. If  you get an error message, show it to us (copy-and-paste it as text, don't summarize or post an image).

Answer (score 0):

You got this fundamentally wrong buddy.

Arm32 can't use 64 bit integer due to it's nature "Arm32".

Arm32:
Rn = 32 bit integer

Arm64: 
Wn = 32 bit integer 
Xn = 64 bit integer